# how to copy file to system folder in batch

Tags: batch-file, copy, system

i want to copy a file to system32 folder using a batch file. but when i try to do this it says `"Access denied"` i also can not copy anything to my C:\ drive also. i tried using `xcopy and copy` to do this. i don't know what is the parameter to get the administrator permission. so, can anyone help me?

program:

```
@echo off  
xcopy abc.dll "C:\Windows\System32\" -y  
pause
```

output:

```
D:abc.dll  
Access denied  
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You are doing something that is not permitted for security reasons. Why are you trying to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be doable one of two ways.

The first is to make a shortcut to your batch file, right click -> properties and on the **Shortcut** tab of the properties, click the Advanced button to find a checkable "run as admin" option.

The second (NOT TESTED) is to add a bunch of stuff to the top of your batch file ([Reference](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/home/BatchGotAdmin)) - I don't want to include it in the answer because I have not tested it.

Comment: You can't run a shortcut as admin unless you have admin permission to run as admin

Comment: I tested the second way. It works great on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off  
copy /Y abc.dll "C:\Windows\System32\"  
pause
```

right click the batch file and run as administrator
and make sure the abc.dll is in the same folder as your batch file.

hope this helps.